# Automatic microphone gain in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, microphone

In our one-on-one video calling application, we set microphone gain as follows:

```
mic.gain = 50;
```

The problem is that in some of the calls, the other party comes through very softly. We'd like to automatically increase their microphone gain in such situations.

There seems to have been the `MicrophoneEnhancedOptions.autoGain` property that allowed just for this. It's hinted at in the [Flash Player 10.3 announcement](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/03/introducing-flash-player-10-3-beta.html); it also appears in Flash Builder's code complete pop-up. However, this property isn't in the current documentation and seems to always stay at `false` no matter what we set it to:

```
var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();
var options:MicrophoneEnhancedOptions = mic.enhancedOptions;
options.autoGain = true;
mic.enhancedOptions = options;
trace(String(mic.enhancedOptions.autoGain)); // Outputs "false"
```

Please share any suggestions for the automatic gain control in Flex, via `MicrophoneEnhancedOptions.autoGain` or otherwise.

Comment: When you say "seems to always stay at false" do you mean that you set it to true, but query the value and it's still false? Or you set it to true and it doesn't seem to do anything? It can't hurt to show the code that you're using.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what's happening. Code added.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like Adobe planned on developing that feature but changed their mind :) One other thing we should clarify: are you seeing this in a mobile IOS app (where the enhanced mic features aren't supported)? PS: I wasn't aware of this feature at all, in the past we wrote some code so that one user could increase the gain of the another user in the video chat ... that worked really well.

Comment: Yeah, I got that impression too; that whole situation with the autoGain property looks really weird. The application is a desktop one and we're able to use the other enhanced mic features no problem. We'd like to avoid manual interaction as much as possible but if that's inevitable, should the volume control on the user's end increase _the other user's gain_, or increase the _output volume_ for the incoming stream? Alternatively, how feasible would it be to implement auto gain in ActionScript?

Comment: Doing auto again yourself seems possible: if the Microphone.activityLevel falls below a threshold, increase the gain. I used the activityLevel to build an indicator so the user could see how much sound was being detected from the mic. In our case the video chat had 1-4 people in it, with n number of viewers. The "producer" of the chat had a separate control to increase the gain of the "quiet" user. Increasing the the quiet user's gain was the only option, we couldn't increase the other user's volume since there could be multiple people in the chat, then the "non-quiet" users would be too loud.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience, that makes total sense. I think what we'll do is try to implement simple auto gain control in ActionScript and see how it goes.

Comment: @jamix Did you ever implement this? We're experiencing clipping on an audio when we try and convert a recorded WAV to MP3 when the volume is too high in ActionScript. I tried altering the microphone gain whenever the activity level hits a certain point, but with no luck.